# Image not showing in div

Tags: html, css

Tried every solution from stackoverflow but my div not showing image :

My div with id:

```
<div id="topImage">
</div>
```

and Style :

```
#topImage{
  position:absolute;
  background-image:url("images/image.jpg");
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
  width:100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

[Screenshot of image path.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWP4G.png)

Image available at proper location. Checked and confirmed

Thanks in Advance.

Folder structure:

```
index.html
css /
  -- style.css
  -- images /
     -- image.jpg
```

Comment: can you explain what you mean empty box. I want to show search box over image

Comment: If you use your dev tools to inspect your `#topImage` element, what is it giving you for an error?

Comment: Is your CSS file being called correctly from your HTML? Post the HTML where you link `style.css`

Answer (score 0):

**A)** Be careful using relative paths in CSS. Absolute paths give more predictable result.

**B)** Also it is not very clear which width the div will have without seeing the rest of the code. Check it's size via devtools or just specify the exact width in px.

Try this way:

```
#topImage {
  position:absolute;
  background-image:url("/css/images/image.jpg");
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: that's what i posted check my css

Comment: The `images` folder is inside of the `css` folder.

Comment: if you know how to post path then i have used proper path sir

Comment: 1. Relative and absolute paths both give predictable results - in fact, I would argue against absolute paths in CSS. 2. A div with the width of 100% will work, as it's 100% of whatever the nearest parent with a position set is.

Answer (score 0):

Move the images folder out of the css folder and use the slash at the beginning of your path.

Your folder structure should look like this:

```
index.html 
css / 
    -- style.css
images / 
    -- image.jpg
```

And your styling in CSS:

```
#topImage{
  position:absolute;
  background-image:url("/images/image.jpg");
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
  width:100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Please do not forget to use the slash in front of the images folder in your path name